# Slave server is unable to connect to master server in MySQL Group Replication, status showing Covering , after some time shown error

Tags: mysql, redhat, mysql-group-replication

I am using MySQL 5.7 to configure Group Replication, After Starting Group replication on Slave server, Status of Slave Server is showing Covering and after some time , it's shown error.

After running below MySQL Query, I am getting 1045 error .

```
select * from   performance_schema.replication_connection_status\G
```

After that i have tried to login manually using same mysql user and Password then it is successful.

I have completed every steps according to mentioned in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-configuring-instances.html

Anyone, if you know better answer, please help to resolve this issue.

I have attached status output of slave server.

Screenshot of status of replication channel
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when we try to create Group Replication cluster manually.

1. First we need to carefully update configurations to comply with group replication prerequisites.

   - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-requirements.html
2. Then the InnoDB cluster setup should be done using MySQL Shell AdminAPI.

   - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/configuring-production-instances.html

Comment: I am using MySQL5.7, As per my understanding InnoDB cluster is not supported in MySQL5.7. So I am using Group Replication Cluster.